# Threshold of steric hindrance for the axial position in cyclohexanes

Tags: organic-chemistry, cyclohexane

My professor mentioned that isopropyl is able to go into the axial position on the chair conformation of a cyclohexane, while tert-butyl cannot. This made me wonder then, at what point is a substituent on a cyclohexane too sterically hindered to ring flip to the axial position?

More specifically, is there a specific [A value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_value) threshold for which a substituent is too sterically hindered to be in the axial position on a cyclohexane?